# Matlab Dirichlet kernel equivalent in Python?

Tags: python, signal-processing

Is there an equivalent in Python for Matlab [diric](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/diric.html)? The [Dirichlet kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_kernel) D<sub>L</sub>(ω) is: D<sub>L</sub>(ω) = sin(ωL/2) / sin (ω/2)

I found [scipy.stats.Dirichlet](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.dirichlet.html), but that's not related. That's no big deal to write the expanded form, but there is a limit to manage: D<sub>L</sub>(0) = L.

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.diric.html is also from the scipy package and doesn't include the summation term.  Dunno if it works at $\omega=0$ or if you need fractional $L$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the [SciPy "special" Dirichlet function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.diric.html)